# Harris Corner Detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm doing a program to detect corners using Harris method. The output of the method shows the corners. What I want to do is to apply thresholding to the image. This is my code:

```
 % Create a mask for deteting the vertical edges 
 verticalMask = [-1 0 1;
            -2 0 2;
            -1 0 1]* 0.25;

% Create a mask for deteting the horizontal edges 
horisontalMask = [-1 -2 -1;
              0 0 0;
              1 2 1]* 0.25;

% Create a mask for Gaussian filter(is used to improve the result)

gaussianFilter= [1 4 1;
             4 7 4;
             1 4 1].*(1/27);


K = 0.04; % The sensitivity factor used in the Harris detection algorithm (Used to detect
            sharp corners).



% Get the gradient of the image [Ix,Iy], using the convulation function
Ix = conv2(grayImage,verticalMask);
Iy = conv2(grayImage,horisontalMask);


% get the input arguments of the harris formula

Ix2 = Ix.* Ix; % get Ix to the power of two
Iy2 = Iy.* Iy; % get Iy to the power of two
Ixy = Ix .* Iy; %get the Ixy by multiply Ix and Iy

% Apply the gaussian filter to the the arguments
Ix2 = conv2(Ix2,gaussianFilter);
Iy2 = conv2(Iy2,gaussianFilter);
Ixy = conv2(Ixy,gaussianFilter);

% Enetr the arguments into the formula
C = (Ix2 .* Iy2) - (Ixy.^2) - K * ( Ix2 + Iy2 ).^ 2;
```

Now, I want to apply the thresholding to C which is the output of the formula. 
I found a code that I tried, It works perfectly, but I want to understand it first if someone can please explain.(For the thresh and radius variables, I changed their values so It can work with my image).

```
thresh = 0.000999;
radius = 1;
sze = 2*radius + 1;                   % Size of dilation mask
mx = ordfilt2(cim, sze^2, ones(sze));      % Grey-scale dilate

% Make mask to exclude points on borders
bordermask = zeros(size(cim));
bordermask(radius+1:end-radius, radius+1:end-radius) = 1;

% Find maxima, threshold, and apply bordermask
cimmx = (cim==mx) & (cim>thresh) & bordermask;
[r, c] = find(cimmx);     % Return coordinates of corners

figure, imshow(im),
hold on;
plot(c, r, '+');
hold off;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first,each pixel of the image `cim` is replaced with the value of its largest neighbor.
The neighbor hood is define as a square of the size `sze`. This dilates the image, i.e. bright image regions get thicker. see [matlab doc](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html)

```
 mx = ordfilt2(cim, sze^2, ones(sze));      % Grey-scale dilate
```

`cim==mx` means that you only accept pixels that are the same in the original and the dialted image. This includes only pixels that are maxima in their neigborhood of size `sze`.

`cim>thresh` means that you only take pixels into account that have a value greater than `thresh`. Hence, all darker pixels cannot be edges.

The border mask makes sure you accept only pixels that have a distance greater than `radius` to the border of the image.

`[r, c] = find(cimmx)` gives you row and column of the corner pixels.